# change AutoCompleteTextView focus border color

Tags: android, colors, textview, autocompletetextview

in my project i have several AutoCompleteTextView.
I want to change this annoying orange border when some of them focused, but don't know how to do this.
[image]

I've been tried some different selectors for textcolor and background but i had no effect.maybe i've done something wrong..

Please help me.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the background of your EditText using a "selector" background (one drawable for each state of the view).

see http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget for details